# Access property outside of method it is stored in

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
[_weatherAPI currentWeatherByCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude) withCallback:^(NSError *error, NSDictionary *result) {
    downloadCount++;
    if (downloadCount > 1)
        if (error) {
        }

    _saveTemp = result[@"main"][@"temp"];
```

In this method I am saving the temp into a NSString.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *saveTemp;
```

How do I access the value of this NSString outside this method? For example I am trying to do this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"%@", _saveTemp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `self.saveTemp`?

Also you should be making the property `strong`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *saveTemp;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is exactly right, except that at the time of viewDidLoad the _weatherApi... Thing has not been called, therefore _saveTemp is uninitialized.  You should really set it in the _weather thing with [self setSaveTemp:...] in order to have it properly retain.

Comment: Can you give a code example please? I am set [self saveTemp] but not sure what to do from there?

Comment: change ' _saveTemp = result[@"main"][@"temp"];'  to [self setSaveTemp:result[@"main"][@"temp"]];   setting directly to the backing ivar circumvents the setter which the compiler is synthesising for you, which will have a hidden retain in it.

Comment: and move the logging attempt to later in the lifecycle, where you know this other method has had time to trigger, perhaps viewDidAppearAnimated: rather than didLoad

Answer (score 0):

Try to create you property with "copy"

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *saveTemp;
```

and try to call setter

```
[self setSaveTemp:result[@"main"][@"temp"]];

-(void)setSaveTemp:(NSString *)saveTemp {
   _sateTemp = saveTemp;
}
```

Comment: Ok I see, how do I then call saveTemp in view did load? As calling NSLog(@"%@", _saveTemp); returns null

Comment: @joshuahornby10 in if you work in one view so in viewDidLoad it will always be nil, because all you methods calling after viewDidLoad, but you can in viewDidLoad call method where you save smth to Temp and after call log you Temp in viewDidLoad. I hope you understand my English :)

Comment: this setter you are writing does not actually implement 'copy' so declaring 'copy' where you prototype the property in the header does nothing except mislead the reader